# PostgreSQL - Is it possible to call Python function from compiled file in SELECT statement?

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql

Is it possible to call Python function from compiled Python *.pyc (*.pyo) file in SELECT statement, like in Oracle SQL DML (like described in https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/java.102/b14187/chseven.htm in paragraph "Calling Java from SQL DML")?

Ie, I want something like

```
SELECT myPythonFunctionFromPycFile(ename, job) AS "Employees" FROM emp
```

P.S. I don't want to decompile *.pyc file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it's impossible now - that's I found after some digging into the Postgresql docs. :(